# Azure Web App Persistent Storage - Container Data Overwritten

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Attempting to enable persistent storage. However, it keeps deleting what's in my container's folder with "hostingstart.html"

Very simple test using apache httpd (following tutorial guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app)):

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   apache:
     image: httpd:latest
#     volumes:
#       - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
```

- Create Resource Group: `az group create --name PandaRG --location "East US"`
- Create App Service Plan: `az appservice plan create --name PandaBearAppPlan --resource-group PandaRG --sku B1 --is-linux`
- Create webapp: `az webapp config container set --resource-group PandaRG --name pandabear --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-apache.yml`
- Navigate to webapp and see default apache page "It works"
- Enable persistent storage: `az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group PandaRG --name pandabear --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE`
- Uncomment `volumes` and `WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME` lines in docker-compose file.
- Update app with new config: `az webapp config container set --resource-group PandaRG --name pandabear --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-apache.yml`
- Navigate back to webapp and see default apache page is gone. Now I see "hostingstart.html" listed

How can I prevent my files from being overwritten when I setup persistent storage?

Answer (score 0):

***This behavior is often observed when Azure App Service initializes and detects an empty directory, so it places the default "hostingstart.html" file there.***

- Here, I have mounted the volumes correctly in the Docker Compose file & pointed to the correct locations for path mapping.

**Webapp with a container configuration:**

```bash
az webapp create --resource-group <RG-name> --plan PandaBearAppPlan --name pandabearfeb04 --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-apache.yml
```

[image]

***Enable persistent storage:***

```bash
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <RG-name> --name pandabearfeb04 --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE
```

[image]

- After deploying the Docker Compose configuration to Azure App Service, navigate to the web app's URL in a browser. I can be able to see the default Apache landing page.

Redeploy the Docker container with the updated `test.html` file to Azure App Service.
[image]

- Once I access the test page, I verified that the content added is displayed correctly. If the content added to the test HTML file, it means that persistent storage setup is working as expected.
  [image]

No change in app settings.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Still wondering why it removes the original "index.html" that I had in my containers /usr/local/apach2/htdocs.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't answer my original question. It's still overwriting the default "index.html" file.

If I want to deploy a container with html files in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs then they will be removed when persistent storage is setup.

Comment: There is a possibility that the volume mounting configuration may not have been properly set up.